# Is it possible to change the screen power off for less than 5 mins. in Cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon

The Cinnamon's power management allows for a minimum of 5 minutes of inactivity to turn off the screen. Is there a way to go below 5 minutes?

Comment: There is, you can set it directly for xorg server, but I forgot how it's done. Try googling for it.

Comment: Do you mean, `xset dpms 60 60 60`? Cinnamon resets the xorg settings after a certain amount of time back to ` 0 0 0 `. I was hoping someone might elaborate on how to prevent that.